# Calculating IRR of a perpetuity with numpy / python

Tags: python, numpy, finance, financial

I am using numpy library for doing simple IRR calculations using the irr function. So for example, if I want to find the IRR of a cash flow, I do the following

```
In [16]:
   import numpy as np 
   cf = np.array([-100,10,10,100])
   print np.irr(a)

0.0688601791248
```

But, I am looking for a way to do the NPV for a perpetuity. My cash flow would be -100, 10....

Has anyone done this before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PV of a perpetuity is simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_value#Annuities.2C_perpetuities_and_other_common_forms):

```
PV=C/i

Where C = amount of cash flows
      i = effective periodic interest rate or rate of return
```